# Regex to search for everything before a string, and after

Tags: regex, yahoo-pipes

I would like to search for everything before the string `http://thepaperwall.com/wallpapers/` but not including that string.
I would also like to search for everything after `.jpg` but not including `.jpg`.

So my final string should look like this:

```
http://thepaperwall.com/wallpapers/cityscape/small/small_642331afcd78d0840485bb352d99b289b50e8467.jpg
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You want to achieve this with what programming language ? Also, what have you tried so far? Where is your code?

Comment: I'm trying to do this in Yahoo Pipes, 
I tried ^.*?http://thepaperwall.com/wallpapers/ but that deletes http://thepaperwall.com/wallpapers/ which I don't want it to

Comment: Go straigth to the yahoo-pipes documentation will help. I found this tuto for you : http://brooksbayne.wordpress.com/2009/01/11/using-regular-expressions-with-yahoo-pipes/  OR  http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=operators#Regex

Comment: Related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2241789/extracting-number-preceding-a-particular-text-using-a-regex

Answer (score 2):

You can use look-behind and look-ahead to get a string position between 2 other strings:

```
(?<=http://thepaperwall.com/wallpapers/).*(?=\.jpg)
```

Comment: How the hell could you figure out OP was about yahoo-pipes regex ?

Comment: I want to delete everything before and after those strings

Comment: Like, how would I search the opposite of that?

Comment: I didn't figure out, it's a generic regex. What do you mean opposite?

Comment: OK so that expression above matches everything between those 2 strings, I want everything outside of those 2 strings so I can replace them with a blank

Comment: You changed your question but now it's half way between old and new version. I'm not exactly sure what you want.

Comment: search for text before string but not including string, search for text after string but not including string

Comment: so if I had this sentence, "Hello, I'm John Marshall"
and I want to delete everything before "I'm" but not including "I'm" and I want to delete everything after "John" but not including "John"
So I should end up with "I'm John"

Answer (score 0):

You need a non-capturing group:

```
(.*)(?:http:\/\/thepaperwall\.com\/wallpapers\/.*\.jpg)(.*)
```

[Live demo](http://regex101.com/r/hU1jF7)